# Razor intellisense and code formatting with MVC 4

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have just integrated MVC into my Asp.Net *website* project.

Its working, but my Razor code is missing formatted as code (e.g. yellow background for the @ character.

Additionally there is no intellisense:

[image]

Here are my MVC related references from web.config

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
<add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
<add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
<add assembly="System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
<add assembly="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
<add assembly="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

Comment: What Intellisense do you expect with ViewBag?

Comment: It's not specific to ViewBag, but I would expect to see "Title" when typing "Viewbag." for instance

Comment: why would you expect anything like this? ViewBag is a dynamic type whose resolution is done at runtime. You cannot expect any Intellisense out of weak types such as ViewData/ViewBag. Use strongly typed views and view models if you want compile-time safety.

Comment: On your case, do you get intellisense when you type `@model MvcApplication1.` at the top of your view? if so, it is working fine to me.

Comment: @MatthewEvans do you have this problem with Visual Studio 11 Dev. Preview? I realized that inside @{} block, there is no C# intellisence at all on VS 11 Dev. Preview.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov : even dynamic types expose things like ToString() via intellisense. The point is I am not getting intellisense. I am not using ViewBag, this is an example page output via a tool.

Comment: @tugberk - no, not Visual Studio 11 preview. Visual Studio 2010, with Asp.NEt MVC 4. I have a number of previous installations of the MVC framework on my PC going to uninstall and see if that helps.

Comment: @tugberk: re your first comment, no I don't get any Intellisense on MvcApplication1. either.

Comment: @MatthewEvans Your case is different then.

Comment: People all over my workplace are getting errors with MVC4. In particular there will be a prompt asking the you to reinstall Razor Syntax 1.0 when you start VS2010 SP1, even if you go through it, it will prompt you again next time. After that it still won't give you intellisense on Razor Views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what fixed this:

I uninstalled all versions of MVC framework, re-installed MVC 4, and upgraded ReSharper to v 6

However, I am still not getting syntax highlighting ( the @ character is not yellow)

Answer (score 1):

Please try building the project and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `Web.config` under the `View` folder

`configSections->sectionGroup` and sections. The Version numbers should be `2.0.0.0`
All other version in the file should be `4.0.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

On december 5 2013 i installed the latest updates for visual Studio 2012. Right after that, the cshtml in my mvc4 project went like it apprears in Notepad: not good!

I uninstalled via the package manager, MVC4, restarted VS2012 and installed it again. After that everything looked right again: the syntax highlighting worked again.
I use VS2012 professional.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the .cshtml file was not included in the project.
I checked in Solution explorer, it was not showing under my View folder.

I chose "Show All files" at top of solution explorer buttons.
My cshtml file started showing but icon in dotted lines, so right click on it >> Include in the project.

and building the solution, includes my cshtml file in the project. and now everything's works fine.